# How to measure Retrofit networking duration?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'd like to measure the duration of whole Retrofit networking duration, peer to peer. Is there way to do that specifying any code while Retrofit build or OkHttp builders creation? I'd like to measure the duration of all networking communication.

Comment: Please elaborate your purpose first

Comment: I said what I intend to do explicitly... Is any info that you are missing? @LalitKushwah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use new `OkHttp` `EventListener` API: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events

You can measure network duration with saving difference between `callStart` and `callEnd`